# Not enough values to unpack when I run code in terminal

Tags: python, utf-8, argv

I am a beginner trying to learn Python using the book "Learn Python 3 the hard way"
I understand the concept of this exercise - passing three values to the command line but I don't know what the third value is:

```
import sys
script, input_encoding, error = sys.argv # command line argument (sys.argv)


def main(language_file, encoding, errors):
    line = language_file.readline()

    if line:
        print_line(line, encoding, errors)
        return main(language_file, encoding, errors)


def print_line(line, encoding, errors):
    next_lang = line.strip()
    raw_bytes = next_lang.encode(encoding, errors=errors)
    cooked_string = raw_bytes.decode(encoding, errors=errors)

    print(raw_bytes, "<===>", cooked_string)


languages = open("languages.txt", encoding="utf-8")

main(languages, input_encoding, errors)
```

I am using Ubuntu so I run `python3 ex23.py language.txt`, which is the encoded text file but don't know what the third value is that I have to call for this script to run? It's not made clear in the book. I have also been told that there are issues with the code from someone on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Note that you have errors with final s everywhere else in your script. It's unclear from this code what the other parameter should be. Just add anything and see. Anyway, there are quite a lot of issues with this book, to the point that many actively disrecommend it.

Comment: Yes, I have heard a few on the forums, but as I am a beginner I don't really know what I should look for in a book that's good.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably from the line:

```
script, input_encoding, error = sys.argv # command line argument (sys.argv)
```

That line tries to assign the arguments in `sys.argv` to those three variables but there are not enough values given in the execution of the script.

i.e. For you script to work with that code, you need to call it like:

```
python3 ex23.py arg1 arg2 # the first argument (argument 0) is the script itself
```

Please be aware that while this will solve your problem, this is not the best way to achieve that, as it will work only if the correct amount of arguments is given.

You should either check the len of sys.argv before, like that:

```
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Not enough arguments given", file=sys.stderr)
    exit()
```

And even better, try using the [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `errors` argument gets passed through to `encode` and `decode`, presumably so you can see the effect of different error handling strategies. If the book doesn't try to explain this in the section which contains this exercise, that's one more flaw (but hard to imagine they would present such a weird script without explaining its purpose).

The Python on-line documentation has a table of the various error handling strategies at https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers - in brief, the third argument can be a string like `strict`, `ignore` etc to see how this affects Python's handling of encoding and decoding errors.

The exercise requires you to download a file `languages.txt` which exhibits various encoding and decoding errors for you to play around with; without suitable input data, the example program is probably (even more) worthless.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to pass 2 arguments in the command line here. The first value from argv is always simply the script's name. For example:

```
import sys
x = sys.argv
print(x)
```

Will print "ex23.py" or whatever the filename is.

For this exercise, you don't specify the text file name in the terminal, only the encoding and error parameter. So the script should be started as such in the terminal:

python3.6 ex23.py utf-8 strict

Refer to the bottom of page 107 in the pdf (assuming you have the same version I do, page number may differ.

Edit: in the bottom line of the script:

```
main(languages, input_encoding, errors)
```

the last argument should simply be error:

```
main(languages, input_encoding, error)
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it was the 's' on the end of error that was stopping it from running. Good luck with the book!